# Not able to hit any Breakpoints in WebStorm, even in very simple setting

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, breakpoints

Even in an extremely simple setting, I'm unable to get any breakpoints in my code to hit. See the attached screenshot. After hitting 'Debug "main.js"', the execution is never interrupted.

[image]

Comment: What's your Node version?

Comment: @LazyOne v7.4.0

Comment: Either downgrade node to v6 or WebStorm to older version: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000018310/comments/115000028050

Comment: You may also try 2017.1 version -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, downgrading to Node.js v6.x worked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Node v7.x ... the solution for now is:

- either downgrade Node to v6.x
- or WebStorm to older version.

From [this official comment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000018310/comments/115000028050):

> Are you using Node 7.x? It's a known issue unfortunately, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24629. Hidden option for turning dev tools protocol support off (`js.debugger.node.use.inspect=false`) will be included in next 2016.3 update - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24629#comment=27-1809582.
>
> For now the only workaround is downgrading Node.js to 6.x :( Full Node 7 support (using v8 inspector) will be available in 2017.1

---

You may also try latest EAP build of 2017.1 -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP -- it may have that fix already available (sorry, not using NodeJS myself so cannot confirm it).